# Show $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x \neq \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x \neq  \frac{1}{3}$.

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x \neq  \frac{1}{3}$ because

$$\exists \varepsilon = \frac{1}{5} : \forall N \exists n > N : |\sin x - \frac{1}{3}| \geq |\frac{-1}{3}| \geq \frac{1}{5} = \varepsilon$$

Comment: What do $x$ and $n$ have to do with each other?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You don't need to claim that there exists $1/5$. More importantly, what is $N$? Why is $|\sin x - 1/3| \geq |-1/3|$? That's certainly not true if, for eample, $\sin x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\sin(2n\pi)-\frac{1}{3}\right|=\frac{1}{3}>0$$ for all $n$, and this prove the claim.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sin x$ does not exist.

As, you should know that : If a sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_n$ namely $(x_n)_n$ converges to $a$, then the sequence $f(x_1),f(x_2),\dots,f(x_n)\to f(a)$.

Now, consider two sequence $x_n=2n\pi$ and $y_n=(4n+1)\frac\pi 2$. Note that, as $n\to\infty$, $x_n\to\infty$,$y_n\to\infty$.

But, $\sin (x_n)\to 0$ and $\sin (y_n)\to 1$, which contradicts the [Heine's definition of limit](http://www.math24.net/definition-of-limit-of-function.html), so, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sin x$  does not exist.